# Solving a mootools error / conflict using Gantry Framework on J3.0.2

Tags: javascript, joomla, mootools, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I am having problems finding the solution to two errors on a web site I am building on a Joomla 3.0.2 platform and using the Gantry Framework.

The first error is:

**Type issue**

**'null' is not an object (evaluating 'b.appendChild')**

The second error is:

**Type issue**

**'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'rikgallery_slideshow.jump')**

I have never understood how to debug javascript errors, so I would really appreciate some help.

The site can be accessed at: http://lads.ergonomiq.net

If someone can help and needs super user access to the back end, please email me at ali.samii@ergonomiq.net

Thanks

Comment: This is probably something you should post on the Rockettheme forums as they are the developers of Gantry

Comment: I have. I am trying to be proactive and solve the issue myself if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is meant to simply point you in the right direction, further testing will be required to fully solve your issues.

OK the first error is happening in **responsive.js** line 66

```
menu.inject(document.getElement('.menu-block'));
```

I would `console.log(menu, document.getElement('.menu-block'))` make sure both contain an element as expected. I am guessing one of those will be null.

Second error

```
AjaxURL: 'http://lads.ergonomiq.net//index.php?option=com_roksprocket&amp;task=ajax&amp;format=raw&amp;ItemId=101'
```

is returning unexpected JSON

```
{"status":"error","message":"Unable to find class for item ","payload":null}
```

I would test the error and only proceed if you have images in your returned JSON

Line 136 of your home page.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Tim. How do I implement the console.log test?

Comment: @lodder hi. Thanks for cleaning up the code. I have a question re how do I implement the suggested test? For example, what do I modify and how do I modify it to implement the test `console.log(menu, document.getElement('.menu-block'))`? Thanks

Comment: on line 65 of responsive.js copy and paste console.log(menu, document.getElement('.menu-block')); then look at your console in firebug or chrome dev tools. it will give you two values. The code is expecting 2 elements. One of those is null. That will then tell you what to look for in your HTML and either adjust the selector there or in your JS.

Comment: @lodder Tim, your code wasn't messy at all. But Lodder just formatted it nicely for you. :)

Comment: on line 65 of responsive.js it has `if (query == '(min-width: 883px)'){
    menu.inject(document.getElement('.menu-block'));
    this.slide.wrapper.setStyle('display', 'none');
    this.toggler.setStyle('display', 'none');
   } else {
    menu.inject(container);
    this.slide.wrapper.setStyle('display', 'inherit');
    this.toggler.setStyle('display', 'block');
   }`. I pasted `console.log(menu, document.getElement('.menu-block'))` right before the if statement and it an error of _Semantic issue Unexpected token 'if'_. I guess I pasted it incorrectly. How would I paste it?

Comment: Place your cursor after the curly brace from the if statement. then press enter. now paste console.log(menu, document.getElement('.menu-block')); Visit the page with chrome or firefox then look at your console in firebug or chrome dev tools. it will give you two values. The code is expecting 2 elements. One of those is null. That will then tell you what to look for in your HTML and either adjust the selector there or in your JS

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21075/discussion-between-alisamii-and-timwickstrom-com)

Answer (score 0):

> I have never understood how to debug javascript errors, so I would
>   really appreciate some help.

If you want to debug JavaScript errors, you should be using [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) with the FireFox browser. You can get the [FireBug Add-on here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/). You will then be able to find these bugs yourself.

Comment: Or (possibly more robust option) dev tools in Google Chrome